# Pinned item inside silverlight scrollviewer

Tags: silverlight, scrollviewer

Is there a way to have a control inside silverlight scrollviewer that does not scroll?  For example I would like the similar behavior as you get when pinning a column in a datagrid so that I can have a footer to my listbox but still have it fit inside the scroll bars (looks better that way).  here is a screen shot of what I have.  The control I want inside is at the bottom.

[image]

Per request here is my control template for the listbox.  I have a template for scrollviewer to but could not find a way to tell it to leave the border at bottom when scrolling everything else.  If you look at the template I have the border outside of the scrollviewer to keep it from being scrolled but would like it to fit inside the scrollbar because I think it looks better.

```
 <ControlTemplate TargetType="telerik:RadListBox">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Border BorderThickness="0" Background="{StaticResource ListBoxBackground}" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                        </Border>
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ScrollViewer"
                            Margin="0"
                            IsTabStop="False"
                            HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                            TabNavigation="{TemplateBinding TabNavigation}"
                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                      Style="{StaticResource ScrollViewerStyle}">

                            <ItemsPresenter/>

                        </ScrollViewer>
                        <Border Grid.Row="1" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Tan" BorderThickness="1" Height="50">
                            <TextBlock Text="Dont scroll but keep in scrollviewer"  TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                        </Border>

                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="dragVisualPlaceholder" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>

                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Can you show your existing codes ?

Comment: I'd move your pinned items outside of the ScrollViewer into a separate ItemsControl. Perhaps put the ScrollViewer and ItemsControl inside a DockPanel with the ItemsControl docked bottom.